# How to change IP address without VPN/proxy locally?

Tags: web-scraping, request, ip

I'm building a scraper, and in order to not get banned, I have to make my requests from different IP addresses. Right now I'm doing that with a VPN, but it has several issues.

As I was reading about the topic, everybody was advising the methods I currently use, but those have their own problems.

I noticed that connecting to the same network from different devices gives different IP address. Furthermore, the same device connected to the same network, through WiFi, or through LAN gives different IP address. I'm not too experienced in networks, and don't know if those different addresses are really different, or will reveal that the requests are coming from the same network, but may be a good idea.

And if it is, how can I take advantage of it? Is there a way to programmatically create "fake devices" from the same device, getting different IP addresses? (I'm thinking about VMs or something)

Comment: The devices / vms will have different local ip addresses but will share the same public one. The only way to change the ip that a website sees is with proxy / vpn.

Answer (score 0):

Your **public IP** address is the one allocated to you (or to a group of Internet users you belong to) by your Internet provider.

On your side of your Internet box, the IP addresses are **local addresses**. Those local addresses cannot be seen from the outside. So you can change your local IP address as much as you want, the outside world will see you with the same IP.

Your solution could be to rent a server on the cloud and run your scraper on it.